# Change Jquery UI Dialog title Dynamically according to the selected row (html table)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using JQuery UI Dialog to show some specific details for a selected row (in html table).

When the user click on a row (where there is an image), the Dialog is opened and it contains an html table too with additional details for the selected row.

What i would like to do?
Add a dynamic title according to the specific selected row

**My Dialog:**

```
$("#conteneurop").dialog({
width: 900,
height: 450,
modal: true,
position: 'center',
overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'},
autoOpen: false,
buttons: {
"close": function() {                   
$( this ).dialog( "close" );                    
}}
});
```

**When the user click on the image:**

```
$('#container tbody tr td img').live('click',function(){
ajaxCall($(this).attr('id'));   
})
```

**The call of the Dialog itself**

```
function ajaxCall(datos){                   
$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "operators.php",
data: "datos="+datos,
success: function(oper)
{
$("#conteneurop").dialog('open').html(oper);
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`$("#conteneurop").dialog('option', 'title', 'New Title');`

Comment: are you sure your ajaxCall succeed? tried to catch an error?

Comment: is your browser console tells you anything usable? Press F12: For Debugging mode. unter "console" you should see if something is going wrong when you trigger the ajaxCall

Comment: i have no problem, i just wanna to change dynamucally the title of the Dialog according to the selected row.

Comment: the last thing i would try is to change the title with an jquery selector. something like $("title selector").text('New Title'); when that's not working then your ajaxCall seems not so succeed. tried to debug with consol.log('test')?

Comment: if my ajaxCall doesn't succeed, it will never open the Dialog !! but the Dialog is opened and show me the data